# I got a validation error while hitting an API

Tags: javascript, postman, nestjs

I got an error of [image] while hitting an API

[image]

Here is the code of DTO

```
import {IsString, IsInt,IsEmail,IsNotEmpty, IsNumberString} from 'class-validator'

export class tokendto{
    @IsInt()
    token:number
}
```

here is the code of controller

```
@Get('get')
data(@Body()token:tokendto){
  return this.crudservice.getdata(token)
}
```

here is the code of services

```
async getdata(token:tokendto):Promise<any>{
  const data=await this.stuentmodel.find().exec()
  return data
}
```

Comment: How do you set token in postman?

Comment: sorry my fault,question updated please check

Comment: You're submitting the token as string `"123"`, while the API expects an integer (ie `123`).

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `"123"` (string value), which would be okay with the validator `@IsNumberString`. But `@IsInt` ensures that the value **is** an integer value, meaning that it should be `123`.